# Curious why my onPressed function is not working in debug mode flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement simple bottom sheet in flutter in onPressed method

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  void _onButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => new Column(
              children: [
                new Container(
                  child: Text('Hello'),
                )
              ],
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
        body: new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => _onButtonPressed(context),
          child: Text('Hello'),
        ),
      );
}
```

So whenever I set my flutterMode in launch file debug mode it shows me exception when I click my button

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3524 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
```

But as I build my application in profile or release mode the bottom sheet works like a charm.
Is this any specific reason for this ?

Cause I have another page which also implements bottom sheet but it works on any of mode.

just built this app on android studio

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3524 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3524:12)
#3      showModalBottomSheet (package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:667:65)
#4      _LoginScreen._onButtonPressed (package:mahayoga_admin/loginScreen.dart:10:5)
#5      _LoginScreen.build.<anonymous closure> (package:mahayoga_admin/loginScreen.dart:29:53)
#6      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#095ab
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(18.8, 44.1)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(44.0, 18.0)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

so I changed my code something like this

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mahayoga_admin/bottomSheetDrawer.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _LoginScreen();
}

class _LoginScreen extends State<LoginScreen> {
  void _onButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            ),
            child: new Container(
              child: Text("Hello world"),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  new RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _onButtonPressed(context))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )));
}
```

Comment: Try to use StatefullWidget  instead of StatelessWidget

Comment: no same error with the StatefulWidget too

Answer (score 0):

To solve this simply wrap it in Container and set the height to screen max height like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ... //You can then have a column warped within a container(height specified)....after that under column use the raised button
      ),
    ),
  }
```

Comment: Did you use exactly what I had given with statefull widget?

Comment: Try adding a child to raised button like a text or icon and instead of => try wrapping with {} and yes please do refer to the modal sheet docs.

Answer (score -1):

Ok sorry guys for bothering everyone but as far as I debugged manually it was the way I was navigating my application through screen. What was happening actually I was jumping to above screen mentioned in my problem statement by checking if the user is authenticated or not in onInit function of previous state. In previous state as I mentioned I implemented bottom sheet. S the implementation was failing and suddenly I was jumping to another screen and thats why in above screen I was not able to get my bottom sheet. So all I have to do was change my navigations properly.